# Can we assign values to a variable in object through a stream in Java8?

Tags: java, collections, lambda, java-stream

```
List<Person> personsInOMwithTypeDsc = personsInOm.stream()
                    .filter(e -> e.getPersonType().getPersonTypeId() ==1 )
                    .forEach(personTypeList.stream()
                            .foreach(d -> d.getPersonTypeId() == 1 )
                            .map(Person::setPersonType(d))
                            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

I want to assign a value to a variable in the first object if the condition in the inner loop matches. Is that possible in java streams ?

Comment: what are you trying to do? A stream pipeline that ends with forEach can't return a List

Comment: What do you mean by "in the first object"?

Comment: The functionality is like iterating two for loops and if-else conditions inside.If the condition matches , I want to assign that value to the variable in the loop of the outer object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without knowing much about your types...

```
List<Person> persons = /*you're getting this from somewhere*/;
persons.stream()
  .filter(person -> person.isSatisfiedByYourConditon())
  .forEach(person -> person.setSomeField("new value"));
```